# Регулярное выражениe

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

В общем есть файл в котором много строк, как мне составить регулярное выражение (пишу на node js), чтобы мне выдавались куски которые начинаются с RESPONSE:, после идет любое кол-во любых символов, а заканчиваться должно XMLRequest. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: `RESPONSE:.*xml` - подходит?

Comment: rf.match(/RESPONSE:.*xml/gm) я так делал, совпадений не находит

Comment: Вставьте ваш тестовый текст в вопрос, пожалуйста. Хочу поэксперементировать

Comment: Против. Ничего не мешает продолжить обсуждение на этом сайте. Просто вставьте ваш текст сюда, если он слишком большой, то вставьте часть текста

Comment: Эта самая часть более 100 строк

Comment: Нельзя вставить из этих 100 например 20 строк?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146519/discussion-between-m1dn1ght-and-eziomercer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант `/RESPONSE:(.|\n)*?XMLRequest/g` - работает как надо

```js
const text = `2022-08-01 15:51:01:308 DEBUG <main> {iScan posAdapter main receiving} [PlLoymaxCommunication] RESPONSE: FIRST <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><XMLResponse><Version>3.2</Version><ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode><Calculates><CalculateResponse ErrorCode="0" 2022-08-01 15:51:01:309 DEBUG <main> {iScan posAdapter main receiving} [PlLoymaxCommunication] *** CALCULATES REQUEST SUCCESSFULLY ENDED ***
2022-08-01 15:51:15:841 DEBUG <main> {iScan posAdapter main receiving} [PlLoymaxCommunication]
2022-08-01 15:51:15:841 DEBUG <main> {iScan posAdapter main receiving} [PlLoymaxCommunication] *** DISCOUNTS REQUEST ***
2022-08-01 15:51:15:841 DEBUG <main> {iScan posAdapter main receiving} [PlLoymaxCommunication]
2022-08-01 15:51:15:842 DEBUG <main> {iScan posAdapter main receiving} [PlLoymaxCommunication] REQUEST: <XMLRequest>
<Version>3.2</Version>
<Discounts>
<DiscountRequest OperationID="2d4ad83a37f947059ed716a8730a2905" DeviceLogicalID="POS71-BO-5475" OperationDate="2022-08-01T15:51:15.841" PurchaseID="9af6bdfe73a74a6cabec574c5cc3136e">
<Cheque ChequeNumber="34165" ChequeDate="2022-08-01T15:50:22.54">
<ChequeLine PosID="1" Amount="139.99" Name="БЗМЖ ПРОСТ.Мол.отб.3,4-4,5%1,5л" Quantity="1.0" GoodsId="4045460">
<ChequeLine PosID="4" Amount="64.99" Name="Лаваш АРМЯНСКИЙ бездрож.250г" Quantity="1.0" GoodsId="4135015">
<Params>
<Param Name="Promotype" Value="REGULAR" Type="string"/>
</Params>
</ChequeLine>
</Cheque>
<Identifier Type="Auto" Value="7789004118485501"/>
<Pays>
<Pay Type="Card" Amount="321.96"/>
</Pays>
<Params>
<Param Name="POSVERSION" Value="12.08.69-SP74" Type="string"/>
<Param Name="POSTYPE" Value="GK" Type="string"/>
<Param Name="IP" Value="10.98.128.33" Type="string"/>
<Param Name="BANKCARDTYPE" Value="MZ" Type="string"/>
</Params>
</DiscountRequest>
</Discounts>
</XMLRequest>
2022-08-01 15:51:01:308 DEBUG <main> {iScan posAdapter main receiving} [PlLoymaxCommunication] RESPONSE: SECOND <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><XMLResponse><Version>3.2</Version><ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode><Calculates><CalculateResponse ErrorCode="0" 2022-08-01 15:51:01:309 DEBUG <main> {iScan posAdapter main receiving} [PlLoymaxCommunication] *** CALCULATES REQUEST SUCCESSFULLY ENDED ***
2022-08-01 15:51:15:841 DEBUG <main> {iScan posAdapter main receiving} [PlLoymaxCommunication]
2022-08-01 15:51:15:841 DEBUG <main> {iScan posAdapter main receiving} [PlLoymaxCommunication] *** DISCOUNTS REQUEST ***
2022-08-01 15:51:15:841 DEBUG <main> {iScan posAdapter main receiving} [PlLoymaxCommunication]
2022-08-01 15:51:15:842 DEBUG <main> {iScan posAdapter main receiving} [PlLoymaxCommunication] REQUEST: <XMLRequest>
<Version>3.2</Version>
<Discounts>
<DiscountRequest OperationID="2d4ad83a37f947059ed716a8730a2905" DeviceLogicalID="POS71-BO-5475" OperationDate="2022-08-01T15:51:15.841" PurchaseID="9af6bdfe73a74a6cabec574c5cc3136e">
<Cheque ChequeNumber="34165" ChequeDate="2022-08-01T15:50:22.54">
<ChequeLine PosID="1" Amount="139.99" Name="БЗМЖ ПРОСТ.Мол.отб.3,4-4,5%1,5л" Quantity="1.0" GoodsId="4045460">
<ChequeLine PosID="4" Amount="64.99" Name="Лаваш АРМЯНСКИЙ бездрож.250г" Quantity="1.0" GoodsId="4135015">
<Params>
<Param Name="Promotype" Value="REGULAR" Type="string"/>
</Params>
</ChequeLine>
</Cheque>
<Identifier Type="Auto" Value="7789004118485501"/>
<Pays>
<Pay Type="Card" Amount="321.96"/>
</Pays>
<Params>
<Param Name="POSVERSION" Value="12.08.69-SP74" Type="string"/>
<Param Name="POSTYPE" Value="GK" Type="string"/>
<Param Name="IP" Value="10.98.128.33" Type="string"/>
<Param Name="BANKCARDTYPE" Value="MZ" Type="string"/>
</Params>
</DiscountRequest>
</Discounts>
</XMLRequest>
`;

const matches = text.match(/RESPONSE:(.|\n)*?XMLRequest/g);

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Comment: @m1dn1ght Погодите, он не работает, по вашим новым условиям. И не надо удалять текст...

Comment: @m1dn1ght Теперь работает как надо. Добавил проверку на наличие перехода на новую строку

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о поиске строк, и нужная подстрока оканчивается расширением ".xml", то следующее выражение должно подойти /^RESPONSE:.*.xml$/g